# Put line numbers inside fancyvrb environment

Tags: verbatim, line-numbering, fancyvrb

Line numbers generated for verbatim text by the fancyvrb package are put outside the verbatim environment:

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left]
First verbatim line.
Second verbatim line.
\end{Verbatim}
Normal text
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

How do I align the numbering in such a way that they are inside the verbatim environment (left aligned with "normal text") and don't go into the page margin?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Use `xleftmargin`:

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,xleftmargin=5mm]
First verbatim line.
Second verbatim line.
\end{Verbatim}
Normal text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness, the `verbatimbox` package can also do this with its optional argument.  In this case, I am using the `verbnobox` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\def\verbarg{{\scriptsize\makebox[2ex]{\arabic{VerbboxLineNo}}}\hspace{2ex}}
\begin{verbnobox}[\verbarg]
First verbatim line.
Second verbatim line.
\end{verbnobox}
Normal text
\end{document}
```

[image]